# Parsing JSON Response in java to extract values

Tags: java, json

What I'm trying to do is get a response, but don't know how to extract the values from it.

The actual response is the following:

```
[
   "SUCCESS",
   [   [
      "Karachi",
      ["کراچی"],
      [],
            {
         "candidate_type": [0],
         "is_confident": [true]
      }
   ]]
]
```

I need to extract `urdu` text from it

```
    String text = "Karachi";            
    String url = "https://inputtools.google.com/request";       
    try {           
         final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            final PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
            method.setParameter("text", text);
            method.setParameter("itc", "ur-t-i0-und");
            method.setParameter("num", "1");
            method.setParameter("cp", "0");
            method.setParameter("cs", "1");
            method.setParameter("ie", "utf-8");     
            client.executeMethod(method);               
            BufferedReader strResponse =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream(),"UTF-8"));
            Object jObj =   (Object) JSON.parse(strResponse);
```

Comment: Are you saying you need to extract the value for some key `urdu`? I'm asking because that would be impossible based on the JSON you've posted (as there is no `urdu` anywhere).

Comment: no i want to extract  ["کراچی"] this value... i am asking about urdu text

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I just want to extract ["کراچی"] this...

Comment: @user1162546 apologies, I didn't know that word.

Comment: this is written in urdu i only need to read this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Your buffer reader may have more than one line):

```
StringBuilder yourJsonString= new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = strResponse.readLine()) != null) {
      yourJsonString.append(line);
}
JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(yourJsonString.toString());
//retrieve the second element of json array
JSONArray secondElmArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray(1);
JSONArray innerArray = secondElmArray.getJSONArray(0);

JSONArray urduList= innerArray.getJSONArray(1);
String urduWord= urduList.getString(0);
```

Comment: can u plz tell me how to parse the above BufferRader string into JsonString.

Comment: ["SUCCESS",[["Karachi", ["کراچی"],[],{"candidate_type":[0],"is_confident":[true]}]]]

this response i am getting but i only need to extract ["کراچی"] from it 
the code you send i have tried it but i am getting **Karachi** but i need   ["کراچی"] this value

Answer (score 0):

I created a wrapper that works fine for all Jsons:

```
package com.myProject.SampleProject;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.json.JSONObject;


/**
* These two dependences will require to use the code
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
*/
public class JsonExtractor {

public static void main(String[] args) {


        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "  \"releases\": [\r\n" + 
                "    {\r\n" + 
                "      \"release_key\": \"e99e39b\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"ship_advice_no\": \"313456\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"source_node_id\": \"1\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"source_node_type\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"level_of_service\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"fulfillment_quantities\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "          \"fulfillment_key\": null,\r\n" + 
                "          \"order_line_key\": \"201807\",\r\n" + 
                "          \"order_line_quantity\": \"1.0\"\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "      ]\r\n" + 
                "    },\r\n" + 
                "    {\r\n" + 
                "      \"release_key\": \"e9b4f604\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"ship_advice_no\": \"3193457\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"source_node_id\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"source_node_type\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"level_of_service\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"fulfillment_quantities\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "          \"fulfillment_key\": null,\r\n" + 
                "          \"order_line_key\": \"2018070\",\r\n" + 
                "          \"order_line_quantity\": \"1.0\"\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "      ]\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "  ]\r\n" + 
                "}";
        String print = getvalueThroughUrl(json, "/releases/[0]/release_key");
        System.out.println(print);
        print = getvalueThroughUrl(json, "/releases/[0]/fulfillment_quantities/[0]/order_line_quantity");
        System.out.println(print);
        print = getvalueThroughUrl(json, "/releases/[0]/ship_advice_no");
        System.out.println(print);
        print = getvalueThroughUrl(json, "/releases/[1]/fulfillment_quantities/[0]/order_line_key");
        System.out.println(print);
        print = getvalueThroughUrl(json, "/releases/[1]/release_key");

    }


    private static String[] getXpathOrder(String url) {
        String[] xpathOrder =  null;
        if(url.contains("&")) {
            xpathOrder = url.split("&");
        }
        else {
        xpathOrder = url.split("/");
        }
        return xpathOrder;
    }


    public static String getvalueThroughUrl(String json, String url) {
        String value = "";
        String[] xpathOrder =  getXpathOrder(url);
        JsonNode rootNode = null;
        String key = "";
        try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        byte[] jsonData = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
//      JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
//      rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
        rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonObject.toString());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
        JsonNode node = null;
        for(int i=1;i<xpathOrder.length;i++) {
            if(node==null)
                node = rootNode;
            if(xpathOrder[i].contains("[")){
                xpathOrder[i] = xpathOrder[i].replace("[", "");
                xpathOrder[i] = xpathOrder[i].replace("]", "");
                node = node.get(Integer.parseInt(xpathOrder[i]));
            }
            else
                node = node.path(xpathOrder[i]);
                key = xpathOrder[i];
        }
        value = node.asText();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("API key: "+key+" value is:"+value);
        return value;
    }


}
```