# How do I extract the "extract" attribute from JSON?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am trying read JSON data from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Russell%27s_paradox).

I am able to read the entire data inside pages attribute using :

```
JSONObject data=(JSONObject)new JSONTokener(IOUtils.toString(new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Russell%27s_paradox"))).nextValue();
String pageName=data.getJSONObject("query").getString("pages");
System.out.println(pageName);
```

I want to get the data from "extract" attribute next from the above mentioned link, which I am unable to. I am new with this and I can't find any resources to learn this.

I tried the following code but I am getting a JSONException.

```
JSONArray arr=data.getJSONArray("pages");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
String def=arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("extract");
System.out.println(def);
}
```

Help.

Comment: Below link would help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473879/parsing-json-response-in-java-to-extract-values][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of the JSON you're trying to parse is this:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "Russell's_paradox",
        "to": "Russell's paradox"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "46095": {
        "pageid": 46095,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Russell's paradox",
        "extract": "..."
      }
```

That is, `pages` inside `query` is an object, not an array.
And then, `extract` is within another nested object, with key `46095`.
You can get to the `extract` field like this:

```
JSONObject pages = data.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages");
for (String key : pages.keySet()) {
    String def = pages.getJSONObject(key).getString("extract");
    System.out.println(def);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I'm getting a `The method keySet() is undefined for the type JSONObject` error.

Comment: @KaushikS perhaps you're using an older version. Can you upgrade to `20160810` ? If not let me know, and the version you're using.

Comment: Thanks brother. Worked perfectly. If it's okay to ask here, can you post some links where I can learn this JSON Parsing with Java, if you can ? @janos

Comment: I don't really know... It seems to me you were stuck mainly due to your lack of understanding of JSON and (implied) JavaScript. I would recommend the book "JavaScript the good parts". For Java I would recommend "Effective Java", but it's not specific to parsing, it's about Java "mastery". So these suggestions are admittedly very broad, but this is the only suggestion I can think of that makes sense in the long run.

Comment: Yes, I am new to JSON and I'm looking for resources to learn. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Using node JS you can get by its attribute name and also navigate to inner nodes by for loop or recursion depending the depth of JSON object. Here is simple example using for loop for 2 level attribute / data of JSON:

```
const jsonStudent = '{"name":"Mond S","fields":{"Age":12,"Class":"Grad 8","School":"In Town"}}';
 get_JSON_Data ();

function println (msg)
{
  if (DEBUG) {
    var jsonDate = (new Date()).toJSON();
    console.log( jsonDate + ' myParser ' + msg);
  }
}

function get_JSON_Data ()
{
  DEBUG = true;
  var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStudent); // This obj is json object made from string 
  for (var k in obj)
  {
    println ("Got Key " + k + " = " + obj [k]);
    if (typeof (obj [k]) == 'object')
    {
      var felds = obj [k];
      for (var f in felds)
        println ( "    Got fields attr " + f + "   = " + felds [f] + ", direct from obj " + obj[k][f]);
    }  
  }
}
```

==== output will be

```
2020-12-26T13:06:47.645Z myXMLParser Got Key name = Mond S
2020-12-26T13:06:47.649Z myXMLParser Got Key fields = [object Object]
2020-12-26T13:06:47.649Z myXMLParser     Got fields attr Age   = 12 ,direct from obj 22
2020-12-26T13:06:47.649Z myXMLParser     Got fields attr Class   = Grad 8 ,direct from obj Grad 8
2020-12-26T13:06:47.649Z myXMLParser     Got fields attr School   = In Town ,direct from obj In Town
```